# Google Drive / Facebook / Dropbox - Upload file from My Website

Tags: asp.net, facebook, google-drive-api, dropbox-api

So I have Mywebsite (ex. MyWeb.Com)
(ASP MVC )
And Users Can upload their photo to my site. Now I want after upload give options upload to Google Drive/Dropbox/Facebook . But user need Login for it.

I not have idea how do it. How make Login forms on my web, and how send files to their account
P.S - Sorry for my English

Please give me some tips.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

for Google Drive you can use simply use JavaScript please go through below link
[Run a Drive app in JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-js)